# What is the best way to initialize a library with a key in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

What would be the best way to initialize a library (.framework) with a key so it will not be lost even in occasional use of it?

One way appears to me would be to have a static var like 
`public static var MY_API_KEY = ""` in a class and set it on application start. Is there a risk that the value may fall back to the default value?

What would be a better way?

For better understanding: Its not about persisting something between launches. Its perfectly fine to setup the library on every application start. (for example to setup googles library you call `GMSServices.provideAPIKey(YourAPIKey)`)

Comment: "Is there a risk that the value may fall back to the default value?" It isn't a risk. It is a certainty. A mere `static` variable is not going to persist between launches of your app.

Comment: Swift itself doesn't have any persistence. You could use something like NSUserDefaults for that.